# Adding maths function in ggplot annotation

Tags: ggplot2, latex

I have a density plot using ggplot and I have a mathematical function I want to add on the graph using  +annotate() or something similar, but I am not sure how to do this.

The symbol I want in latex code is:

```
     $f_{\epsilon}(|R_{i}|)$
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Have you looked at `plotmath`?  Might be a place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
# install.packages("latex2exp")

library(latex2exp)
test <- TeX("$f_{\\epsilon}(|R_{i}|)$")

library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.text(test, gp = gpar(cex=4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try :)